# Canvas5 performance issues drawing multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently creating a game using canvas and javascript and am having performance issues when I attempt to draw many lines.

The user is able to "fire" missiles to the coordinates where the mouse is clicked in an attempt to destroy oncoming meteors, and I want canvas to draw the line progressively from the "turret" to where the user clicked.

This is the function that listens for the click and draws the line to where the user clicks

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {

// uses the function getMousePos to get coords
var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, event);
var endX = mousePos.x;
var endY = mousePos.y;

var amount = 0;
var startX = w/2;
var startY = h; 

// draw the line from turret
setInterval(function() {
    amount += 0.005;
    if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);

    ctx.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount,
            startY + (endY - startY) * amount);

    ctx.stroke();
}, 20);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oohyefwa/

After I draw 10 or so lines canvas becomes incredibly laggy and for a game would be unacceptable.

Are there more efficient ways to do what I'm trying do to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `beginPath()` to your draw loop. If not the lines will accumulate and all will be redrawn over and over eventually lagging down the browser.

**Example**

```
setInterval(function() {
    ctx.beginPath();    // <----

    amount += 0.005;
    if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);

    ctx.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount,
            startY + (endY - startY) * amount);

    ctx.stroke();
}, 20);
})
```

Comment: Such as simple solution.... Thank you!

Another question I have is why do the lines tend to get drawn slower when I click closer to the "turret" compared to clicked further away?

Comment: @koken it's because the distance is longer but the t-value (amount) of the lerp is constant. You need to increase the t value proportionally, for example by dividing the length on x number of segments and use that instead of a fixed value. If you need more details I would suggest opening a new question for it.